# ASP.NET Core MVC Post Request from JQuery but need to redirect from Controller Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have ASP.NET Core 2 MVC project. I am posting some data using JQuery to action.
Suppose User.Identity.Name is null and I want to redirect to AccountController 
AccessDenied action. 
I am unable to use `RedirectToAction` (also removed return). Because this goes back to JQuery success/error.

**Is there any solution to this?**

**IN Controller**

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(User.Identity.Name))
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(AccountController.AccessDenied), "Account");
```

**In My JS**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/MyController/MyAction',
        dataType: "json",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            errorAlert(xhr.responseText, "ERROR");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Let Ajax error function to redirect when server response is access denied.

```
error: function (xhr, status, err) {
    if(xhr.status==401) {
        window.location.replace('@Url.Action("AccessDenied", "Account")');
    } else {
        errorAlert(xhr.responseText, "ERROR");
    };
}
```

From controller return http error 401, so that it will trigger error Ajax function at client.

```
return Unauthorized();
```

Comment: there is a catch then what if something else go wrong like server not answering or 404 action even then it will go to error block aint it?

Answer (score 1):

so here is the deal when you do an ajax call it expects a return value and hence  **you cannot redirect an ajax call from the server side** but you can do one thing u can send the url as string to which you want to redirect and then redirect it from client side ie

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(User.Identity.Name))
    return "YourController/YourAction/ParamifAny";
```

and in controller side

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/MyController/MyAction',
        dataType: "json",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
         window.location.href = data
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            errorAlert(xhr.responseText, "ERROR");
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is not full code. I use success in JQuery as well to reload stuff. So can not use it for href :(

Comment: you can pass in an object instead of string n which a bool status if status is true then dont redirect else redirect